# Vue.js - Element UI - Upload file add a parameter

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2

I'm using `vue.js 2.3` and `element-ui`.

I'd like to use the [upload-file component](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload) to send files to my server.

In the doc we can find the `action` `"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"`

#### Question

I would like to know how can I add a parameter to the action?

#### Situation

I currently receive an array `file` with the data of my file but I would like to be able to pass other parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the list of attributes on [the documentation page you linked to](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload), there is a `data` attribute that lets you specify an object as "addition[al] options of [the] request".

Comment: not able to post data with a file using  element UI